# Почему при unit-тесте рест-контроллера выдаётся ошибка 404?

Tags: java, spring, юнит-тесты, mock

Имеется контроллер:

```
/**
 * REST-контроллер для непосредственной работы с активити
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/process", produces = {"application/json"})
public class ActivitiController {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(ActivitiController.class);

    private final ActivitiService activitiService;

    @Autowired
    public ActivitiController(ActivitiService activitiService) {
        this.activitiService = activitiService;
    }

    /**
     * Стартует процесс в активити
     *
     * @param processName имя процесса, который нужно стартовать
     * @param params      параметры, передаваемые при старте процесса
     * @return идентификатор экземпляра процесса, созданного после старта процесса
     */
    @PostMapping(value = "/start")
    @ResponseBody
    public String startProcess(@RequestParam("processName") String processName, @RequestBody Map<String, String> params ) {
        Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<>();
        params.forEach(variables::put);

        ProcessInstance newProcessInstance = null;
        try {
            newProcessInstance = activitiService.startProcess(processName, variables);
        } catch (ActivitiServiceException e) {
            logger.warn(e);
            return "null";
        }
        return newProcessInstance.getProcessInstanceId();
    }
}
```

Хочу написать для него юнит-тесты с использованием того же `Spring`. Написал такой юнит-тест:

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(value = ActivitiController.class, secure = false)
public class ActivitiControllerTests {

    private static final String TEST_PROCESS_NAME = "process_name";
    private static final String TEST_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID = "12";
    private static final String TEST_TASK_INSTANCE_ID = "14";

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ActivitiService activitiService;
    private ProcessInstance getTestProcessInstance() {
        return new ProcessInstance() {
            @Override
            public String getProcessInstanceId() {
                return TEST_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID;
            }
       };
    }

    @Test
    public void testStartProcess() throws Exception {
        given(activitiService.startProcess(TEST_PROCESS_NAME, Collections.emptyMap()))
                .willReturn(getTestProcessInstance());

        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/process/start")
                        .param("processName", TEST_PROCESS_NAME)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content("{\"key\":\"value\"}"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }
}
```

После запуска выдаёт код ответа `404`, вместо кода `200`.

До этого была ошибка:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a
>   @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or
>   @SpringBootTest(classes=...)

Добавил на уровень выше (в дереве каталогов) пустой класс конфигурации, и ошибка исчезла:
[image: Дерево каталогов с тестами]

Код класса конфигурации:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
public class FakeConfig {}
```

В консоли показывает следующее:

> MockHttpServletRequest:
>         HTTP Method = POST
>         Request URI = /process/start
>          Parameters = {processName=[process_name]}
>             Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json], Accept=[application/json]}
>                Body = 
>       Session Attrs = {}
>
> Handler:
>                Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler
>
> Async:
>       Async started = false
>        Async result = null
>
> Resolved Exception:
>                Type = null
>
> ModelAndView:
>           View name = null
>                View = null
>               Model = null
>
> FlashMap:
>          Attributes = null
>
> MockHttpServletResponse:
>              Status = 404
>       Error message = null
>             Headers = {}
>        Content type = null
>                Body = 
>       Forwarded URL = null    Redirected URL = null
>             Cookies = []
>
> MockHttpServletRequest:
>         HTTP Method = POST
>         Request URI = /process/start
>          Parameters = {processName=[process_name]}
>             Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json], Accept=[application/json]}
>                Body = 
>       Session Attrs = {}
>
> Handler:
>                Type = org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler
>
> Async:
>       Async started = false
>        Async result = null
>
> Resolved Exception:
>                Type = null
>
> ModelAndView:
>           View name = null
>                View = null
>               Model = null
>
> FlashMap:
>          Attributes = null
>
> MockHttpServletResponse:
>              Status = 404
>       Error message = null
>             Headers = {}
>        Content type = null
>                Body = 
>       Forwarded URL = null    Redirected URL = null
>             Cookies = []
>
> java.lang.AssertionError: Status  Expected :200 Actual   :404

Если делаю, как в [примере](https://www.sylvainlemoine.com/2017/11/08/spring-boot-test-howto/), то есть добавляю на уровень выше класс:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String... args){
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class);
    }
}
```

то получаю в консоли следующее:

> MockHttpServletRequest: HTTP Method = POST Request URI =
>   /process/start Parameters = {processName=[process_name]} Headers =
>   {Content-Type=[application/json], Accept=[application/json]} Body =
>   Session Attrs = {}
>
> Handler: Type =
>   ru.cip.rlic.core.api.controller.rest.ActivitiController Method =
>   public java.lang.String
>   ru.cip.rlic.core.api.controller.rest.ActivitiController.startProcess(java.lang.String,java.util.Map)
>
> Async: Async started = false Async result = null
>
> Resolved Exception: Type = null
>
> ModelAndView: View name = null View = null Model = null
>
> FlashMap: Attributes = null
>
> MockHttpServletResponse: Status = 200 Error message = null Headers =
>   {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], Content-Length=[4]}
>   Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8 Body = null Forwarded
>   URL = null Redirected URL = null Cookies = []
>
> MockHttpServletRequest: HTTP Method = POST Request URI =
>   /process/start Parameters = {processName=[process_name]} Headers =
>   {Content-Type=[application/json], Accept=[application/json]} Body =
>   Session Attrs = {}
>
> Handler: Type =
>   ru.cip.rlic.core.api.controller.rest.ActivitiController Method =
>   public java.lang.String
>   ru.cip.rlic.core.api.controller.rest.ActivitiController.startProcess(java.lang.String,java.util.Map)
>
> Async: Async started = false Async result = null
>
> Resolved Exception: Type = null
>
> ModelAndView: View name = null View = null Model = null
>
> FlashMap: Attributes = null
>
> MockHttpServletResponse: Status = 200 Error message = null Headers =
>   {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8], Content-Length=[4]}
>   Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8 Body = null Forwarded
>   URL = null Redirected URL = null Cookies = []
>
> java.lang.AssertionError: Response content Expected :12 Actual :null

Изменил несколько код юнит-теста:

```
    @Test
    public void testStartProcess() throws Exception {
/*        given(activitiService.startProcess(TEST_PROCESS_NAME, new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
            put("pathNumber", 1L);
        }}))
                .willReturn(getTestProcessInstance());*/
        given(activitiService.startProcess(any(), any()))
                .willReturn(getTestProcessInstance());


        mockMvc.perform(
                post("/process/start")
                        .param("processName", TEST_PROCESS_NAME)
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                        .content("{\"pathNumber\":1}"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(TEST_PROCESS_INSTANCE_ID));

    }
```

Так проходит. Теперь надо понять, как сделать, чтобы он принимал нужные мне параметры, и в зависимости от этих параметров возвращал нужный результат. Так что предполагаю, что с DemoApplication всё работает.

Comment: А над каким классом у вас стоит аннотация @SpringBootApplication(точка входа)?

Comment: @AndriiTorzhkov над классом ru.firm.proj.app.web.config.Application

Comment: @AndriiTorzhkov Как должен выглядеть этот класс, чтобы прошло тестирование?

Comment: @AndriiTorzhkov Добавил в ответ некоторую информацию

Comment: @MaxLich Если я не ошибаюсь, если Вы используете пустой FakeConfig как @SpringBootConfiguration, то у Вас просто не регистрируется контроллер -> 404.  
Если делаете, как в  примере (@SpringBootApplication), то тест отрабатывает нормально, просто падает, потому что контроллер возвращает `null`

Comment: @Sergi да. есть некоторые подвижки. Добавлю в описание вопроса.

Comment: @MaxLich, с `@WebMvcTest(value = ActivitiController.class, secure = false)` все тоже должно работать нормально. Скорее всего, у вас падает `activitiService.startProcess(processName, variables);` и вы получате `null` - при этом ошибка должна залогироваться где-то, если лог настроен (или она теряется, если лог не настроен). Смотрите в логах что за ошибка у вас происходит в коде или пробрасывайте exception, так будет намного лучше, чем возвращать `null`

Comment: @Sergi Добавил выбрасывание эксепшена, вместо возвращения "null", + добавил более подробную запись в лог, но это ничего не дало. Я и без этого знал, что этот сервис тупо возвращает null

Comment: @MaxLich че-то я просмотрел - у Вас же `ActivitiService activitiService` - мок, он всегда возвращает `null` на все вызовы методов. Если хотите переопределить поведение мока - используйте `org.mockito.Mockito.when(T)`

Comment: @Sergi Знаю. Для этого по идеи и нужен вызов `given().willReturn`. Но дело в том, что при `any()` он возвращает то, что нужно, это проверяется, и всё ок. Как без `any()` это сделать!?

Comment: @MaxLich вы в   
`given(activitiService.startProcess(TEST_PROCESS_NAME, new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
            put("pathNumber", 1L);
        }}))`  
поменяйте `1L` на `"1"`, потому что у вас в контроллере Map<String,String>.

Comment: @Sergi Да, в этом было дело. Тогда вопрос можно считать решённым.

Comment: @MaxLich супер, можете тогда принять мой ответ, как правильный?

Comment: @ Так как я изначательно спрашивал про конфигурацию, то сейчас вынесу из описания своего вопроса всё, что нужно для решения, в отдельный ответ. Ваш ответ могу только лайкнуть

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю вам не нужен класс FakeConfig.
Так же нужна аннотации над тестирующим классом:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})
```

В вашем случае u.firm.proj.app.web.config.Application.
Дальше вам нужно добавить аннотацию:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

И так же нужно настроить application.properties под папкой test/resources

Comment: А если я хочу простестировать только контроллер!? Про @WebMvcTestм сказано, что он позволяет протестировать только контроллер, но создавая реальных бинов для всех остальных слоёв. Сервер тоже при этом не поднимается. Так что это мне подходит, но не могу разобраться, как запустить тесты с этой аннотацией

Comment: Я вас понял, той аннотацией не пользовался, знаю, что этот вариант рабочий, чем смог, помог

Answer (score 1):

Поменяйте `1L` на `"1"` в

```
given(activitiService.startProcess(TEST_PROCESS_NAME, new HashMap<String, Object>(){{
        put("pathNumber", 1L);
    }})).willReturn(getTestProcessInstance());
```

, так как контролер принимает параметры в виде строк.

Answer (score 0):

Если делать, как в [примере](https://www.sylvainlemoine.com/2017/11/08/spring-boot-test-howto/), то есть добавлять на уровень выше (в дереве каталогов) класс:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class FakeBootApplication {

    public static void main(String... args){
        SpringApplication.run(FakeBootApplication.class);
    }
}
```

то всё работает.

Скриншот дерева каталогов:

[image: Дерево каталогов]